# Run Kubernetes on AWS EC2 Instance only

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I wanted to use *kubernetes* on *AWS EC2*. I have created an *EC2* instance and following this [link1](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/) [link2](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setup-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-ec2/), but it will create master and minion node as new *EC2* instance. In this case there will be more then 3 *EC2* instance will be there.

I am using AWS free tier, thus I can use only one instance for a month, if multiple instance get created then I will get charged.

How can I manage *kubernetes* on run on same *EC2* instance which I created to setup *kubernetes*.

I am using my application for just development, not for production. So now i have to play with aws free tier only.

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I have the same issue.

Comment: i have tried all the possible ways, but no positive result for me. i have to have at least 2 aws instance running to work with kubernetes on aws.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So is that total 2 EC2 instances or 3 instances (1+2)? The Kubernetes script you run in your parent node starts master and minions by default in children node. Were you able to get the master to run in the same machine you started your script and you had one other node for minions?

Comment: no i can't run master in the same machine where i have downloaded and setup kubernetes, i need to delete this instance after setup, else there will be 3 instances. no sure if in newer version kubernetes has added any fix for such issue. i have asked same question in kubernetes git page as well. but no update.

Comment: When you say "this" instance, do you mean your original instance where you ran the script?

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but don't necessarily need minion instances, since the master also deploys pods (if you didn't explicity disabled them).

This means skipping the minion part should work, respectively setting the master count to `1` and the worker count to `0`.

Comment: i have changed that, now 0 minion are getting started, but to install kubernetes i have created 1 EC2 instance where i have supplied `export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash` , and when i started kubernetes its created new EC2 instance for master (separate instance), so now there is 2 instances (1 - Which i created to install kubernetes, 2 - kubernetes master). I would like to get it done in only 1 instance. Because of free tier limit.

Comment: Why do you need an instance to setup Kubernetes? You could either do it from a local machine, a local VM or just delete the setup instance, after.

Comment: how to do it from local machine on aws? can you please help me with link?

Comment: From your question I imply that you are using Windows. You can easily start a Linux from there with [VirtualBox](https://www.lifewire.com/install-ubuntu-linux-windows-10-steps-2202108). If you are using Linux or OSX, then you should be able to run your linked HowTos directly on your machine.

Comment: to start kubernetes with 1 vm i have tried setting export NUM_NODES=0 but its not deploying the image file, all the kubeclt command are working fine, kubenetes is also not working "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",, i got below on kube start up `util.sh: line 292: KUBE_NODE_IP_ADDRESSES: unbound variable`. i have tried this form EC2 instance because still i am trying to figure out how to set kubernetes from local.